# How do I accurately measure a gps track over a long distance?

Tags: gps, line, length

I am measuring the length of the Continental Divide Trail that goes from the Mexican border to the Canadian border. I have a .gpx file of the entire route in NAD83 with tracks about every 50 meters. I've tried two methods:

- If I convert to North America Equidistant and measure the length
  of the line in QGIS and then divide by 1609 (meters in a mile), I get
  2845 miles.
- If I convert to WGS84, measure the length of each line segment and then multiply by the cosine of the latitude, I get 2952 miles.

Published lengths have the trail at about 3050 miles. Which is most accurate? Is there a more accurate method? Do I need a 3d length measurement since the trail goes over mountainous terrain?

Comment: Guessing you mean points every 50m, not tracks. The projection you choose will have an impact on the distance measurement. As you questioned, technically 3D is going to have an impact as well, and greater over longer distances. Yet another factor you haven't mentioned is the accuracy or the GPS data itself. Positional error in each reading can add (or subtract) distance from the actual track, and over great distances this can really add up. I did some hiking in Arches NP with poor signal and might have covered 2.5 miles but the track read 6.6, as one extreme example.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The GPS data looks good. It was taken with a professional GPS. I tried skipping points, but it didn't effect the calculation much. I think the 3d is an important factor. I've roughly calculated that the trail has 80 miles of  vertical up and down.